# How to forget wifi completely with flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make an app where I can get Wifi list around me, connect to a wifi, and disconnect that Wifi completely (including forget the password) like it happens in phone settings.
I'm using 'Wifi_iot' package: https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_iot

to forget Wifi I'm using the wifi_iot built in function

```
static disconnectWifi() {
    WiFiForIoTPlugin.disconnect(); //function from wifi iot package 
  }
```

now it does disconnect my Wifi for a short amount of time but then the Wifi automatically gets connected again. What I could understand that it can not forget the password from the settings...so is there any way to do it?